# Installing azure powershell modules on PS version 4.0 without updating to PS version 5.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

I want to execute the following commands:

```
Install-Module -Name AzureAD
Install-Module -Name MSOnline
```

I am on PSVersion 4, Install-Module works in versions > 4.0, Now upgrading it to PSVersion 5, I will have to download windows management framework 5.1  but that will required restarting the system(I can't restart the system because I don't have permission to).

Is there a way I can install `AzureAD` and `MSOnline` module without updating version to 5 or without restarting the system?